# about conjucation and being abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that any group G of order $105$ has indeed a unique $Sylow-7$ subgroup.
Hint: If G does have not normal subgroup of order $7$ then it has normal subgroup of order $15$. In this case a Sylow-$7$ subgroups acts on this subgroup of order $15$, by conjugation. Next show that G is abelian which yields a contradiction.

Firstly, I can show (If G does have not normal subgroup of order $7$ then) G has normal subgroup of order $15$.

But I dont understand, why must $Sylow-7$ subgroup act on Subgroup of order $15$? and Why does it mean G is abelian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights:

Let $\;Q\lhd G\;$ be of order $\;15\;$ , and let $\;P\;$ a Sylow $\;7$ - subgroup. Then, $\;P\;$ acts on $\;Q\;$ by conjugation:

$$x\in P\;,\;q\in Q\;\implies\;q^x:=x^{-1}qx$$

This action defines a homomorphism $\;P\to\text{Aut}(Q)\;$ , but $\;|\text{Aut}(Q)|=8\;$, so it *must* be that the above action is trivial, meaning $\;q^x=q\;$, and since the above action determines that $\;G=Q\rtimes P\;$ but the action is trivial, $\;G\;$ is in fact a direct product of abelian groups and thus abelian itself.

Comment: how did you know $Q$ is cylic? I mean how is it isomorphic to $Z_{15}$

Comment: There is only one single group of order $\;15\;$ up to isomorphism. This follows at once from Sylow theorems.

Comment: Ok :) thank you for answer, I'm looking that